# @font-face not working WOFF / TFF in chrome

Tags: html, css, font-face, font-family

i have this line first in my css file

```
    @font-face {
    src: url(fonts/VampiroOne-Regular.ttf);
    font-family: vamp;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

then

```
    h1, h2 {
    font-family: vamp;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

And it is not working. what am I missing here that should be written?

Comment: 1. did you check the network tab for 404 errors when loading the font? 2. did you make sure to set `font-weight: normal;` to the `h1` and `h2` tags (As they have a `font-weight: bold` by default)

Comment: @AlonEitan 1. I am not familiar with the network tab, 2. i changed it to font-weight: normal; and the font will not change

Comment: Hit Ctrl+Shift+i to open the developer tools, next select the `Network` tab, then you should refresh the page and after that you can filter the results by `Font` (Or just search for the line of the font in the list)  - See what is the request status (Is it 200 or 404)

Comment: under font status it says; (failed) net:: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out my file path was not right someway.
copied the file path from 'get info' on mac, pasted and it worked fine!

Comment: That's why you should check your console at the first sign of anything going wrong. :)